# Django under IIS (with HeliconZoo) in virtual directory - urls resolver works with path without directory name

Tags: django, iis, url-routing, heliconzoo

I've a Django website running under IIS with a help of Helicon Zoo. It is located in virtual directory (so, url to it looks like `http://mysite.com/django`).

In my urls.py, I have patterns defined like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ....        
    url(r'^django/status/(?P<product>.*)/$',views.status),
    .... 
)
```

But, when I open url like `http://mysite.com/django/status/some_product`
I'm getting 404 page with message:

```
Using the URLconf defined in urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
....
The current URL, status/some_product/, didn't match any of these.
```

As you can see, there is no django in URL which is tested. And of course, when I change pattern like this:

```
url(r'^status/(?P<product>.*)/$',views.status),
```

Everything works fine, but if `APPEND_SLASH` is enabled (and I have it enabled and setting it to `False` in settings.py does not help for some reason), my requests like `http://mysite.com/django/status/some_product` are redirected to `http://mysite.com/status/some_product/`.

So, the question is:
How can I configure Django so it will not throw out virtual directory name?

Is there anything I need to know about how to turn of APPEND_SLASH? 
Right now I simply put `APPEND_SLASH = False` in settings.py, but no difference.

Note: I know almost nothing about Django and Python and I can't change how that website is set up (at least now).

Comment: Probably the request that is received by Django does not contain the full path (including /django/). I suspect that's because of your server configuration.

Comment: Yeah, that may be, but not clear how to figure out which tiny option is responsible for that(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've found what's wrong with it.

Appeared that the reason for described behavior is a setting provided with default web.config file:

```
<add name="django.root" value="%APPL_VIRTUAL_PATH%" />
```

After I removed it everything started working fine.

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/howto/deployment/modpython/) is some info related to `django.root` variable applied to Apache.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that the zoofcgi has two operating modes

[with django_settings_module](https://github.com/alexsilva/helicon-zoofcgi/blob/master/zoofcgi.py#L1051)

[or with wsgi_app](https://github.com/alexsilva/helicon-zoofcgi/blob/master/zoofcgi.py#L1056)

As my project needs the second (wsgi_app), I noticed that the problem was not solved only by setting the variable `django.root`.

That is, there is a bug in the configuration of environmental variables for the second mode. So I created the project [helicon-zoofcgi](https://github.com/alexsilva/helicon-zoofcgi) that solves this bug.

Now there is no need to be entering the site prefix in django urls, the zoofcgi module already solves it in the environment variables.

I hope that the project can be useful for someone in the future.